# jmespath. Change one element in an array depending on type

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

Im use Ansible filter json_query

data:

```
[
  "just_dir",
  {
     "path": "extend_dir",
     "order": "nginx"
  }
]
```

I want to get:

```
[
  {
     "path": "just_dir",
  },
  {
     "path": "extend_dir",
     "order": "nginx"
  }
]
```

```
merage([?type(@) == `string`].{path: @}, [?type(@) == `object`])
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like is not possible to merge to 2 arrays

Github issue: [jmespath.py#152](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/152)

Also you need to add a `from_json` filter before apply it to `json_query`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    data: '[
      "just_dir",
      {
         "path": "extend_dir",
         "order": "nginx"
      }
    ]'
  tasks:
   - name: debug just_dir
     debug: msg="{{ data | from_json  | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
     vars:
       jmesquery: "[?type(@) == `string`].{path: @}"

   - name: debug Other data
     debug: msg="{{ data | from_json  | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
     vars:
       jmesquery: "[?type(@) == `object`]"
```